# How do I calculate $2^\pi$?

Tags: exponentiation, pi

We are taught that $$2^3 = 8$$
Because $$
2\times2\times2 = 8$$
However, how would we calculate something like:
$$2^\pi = \space?$$

Comment: you could use logarithms if you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: use that $$2^\pi=e^{\pi\ln(2)}$$

Answer (score 3):

There is a sequence of rational numbers $a_1,a_2,...$ that converge to $\pi$. Then $$ \displaystyle 2^{\pi} =  2^{\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n}$$

and you know how to calculate $2^{\rm rational\;number}$

Answer (score 3):

Irrational exponents can be expressed as finding increasingly accurate rational approximations of the exponent. For our purposes, we shall use estimates derived from the continued fraction of $\pi$:
$$3, \frac{22}{7}, \frac{333}{106}, \frac{355}{113}, \frac{103993}{33102}, \frac{104348}{33215}, \dots$$
This gives the estimates
$$2^3 = 8$$
$$2^{22/7} = \sqrt[7]{2^{22}} = 8.832716109\dots$$
$$2^{333/106} = \sqrt[106]{2^{333}} = 8.824468786\dots$$
$$2^{355/113} = \sqrt[113]{2^{355}} = 8.824979458\dots$$
$$2^{103993/33102} = \sqrt[33102]{2^{103993}} = 8.824977823\dots$$
$$2^{104348/33215} = \sqrt[33215]{2^{104348}} = 8.824977829\dots$$
$$\vdots$$
$$2^\pi = 8.824977827\dots$$
Alternatively, in the case that we do not have a continued fraction, we could instead just use an increasing number of digits of $\pi$ to approximate this:
$$3, \frac{31}{10}, \frac{314}{100}, \frac{3141}{1000}, \frac{31415}{10000}, \frac{314159}{100000}, \dots$$
This does converges at a slower rate, but still gives the same value.
$$2^3 = 8$$
$$2^{31/10} = \sqrt[10]{2^{31}} = 8.574187700\dots$$
$$2^{314/100} = \sqrt[100]{2^{314}} = 8.815240927\dots$$
$$2^{3141/1000} = \sqrt[1000]{2^{3141}} = 8.821353304\dots$$
$$2^{31415/10000} = \sqrt[10000]{2^{31415}} = 8.8244110824\dots$$
$$2^{314159/100000} = \sqrt[100000]{2^{314159}} = 8.824961595\dots$$
$$\vdots$$
$$2^\pi = 8.824977827\dots$$

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the value of $\pi$, then
$$2^\pi=2^3 \times 2^{\pi-3}=8\times 2^{\pi-3}=8\times e^{(\pi-3)\log(2)}$$ Now, using $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$ with $x=(\pi-3)\log(2)$ would converge quite fast. Adding terms up to $n=p$,we should get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \text{value} \\
 0 & 8.00000000000000 \\
 1 & 8.78515638899013 \\
 2 & 8.82368579868838 \\
 3 & 8.82494628252957 \\
 4 & 8.82497720993398 \\
 5 & 8.82497781700521 \\
 6 & 8.82497782693533 \\
 7 & 8.82497782707456 \\
 8 & 8.82497782707627 \\
 9 & 8.82497782707629 
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the correct value for fifteen significant figures.